# Reusing cell causes unwanted behaviour when updating cell view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want ot set a border to a selected cell, i save a cell property that represents the selected one and manipulate it:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSArray *eyeArray = [self eyesArrayConfigure][indexPath.row];
    if (indexPath.row==5) {
        int r = arc4random() % 6;
        eyeArray = [self eyesArrayConfigure][r];
    }
    [borderedCell.contentView.layer  setBorderWidth:0.0f] ;

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    borderedCell = cell;
    [borderedCell.contentView.layer setBorderColor:self.view.tintColor.CGColor];
    [borderedCell.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:3.0f];

}
```

and the cellForView: (Im usinng 2 types of cell identifiers because one cell contains a label - "Random cell":

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row ==5) {
        UICollectionViewCell *randomCell =[collectionView
                                           dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"randomCell"
                                           forIndexPath:indexPath];
        randomCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
        borderedCell = randomCell;
        [borderedCell.contentView.layer setBorderColor:self.view.tintColor.CGColor];
        [borderedCell.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:3.0f];

        return randomCell;
    }
    UICollectionViewCell *myCell = [collectionView  dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    NSArray *eyeArray = [self eyesArrayConfigure][indexPath.row];

    myCell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:eyeArray[1]];


    return myCell;
}
```

What i get is if a click one cell it will be fine till i scroll and then i get weird behaviour when couple of cells might be with the border.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is what we call a "cell reuse bug".

Comment: So what is the best way to approach it? with "Tag"ing the cells ?

Comment: Use a view model, I'm writing up an answer now.

Comment: I'll let @CrimsonChris finish his answer (he/she gives good answers).  In a nutshell, only the cellForItemAtIndexPath method should ever change the state of a cell.  In your case it should do so based on the selection state recorded in the other select method.  But where to record that state?  In the model of course.  That's the "view model" CrimsonChris refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use a view model. You are already doing this for your cells' background views. Apply the same concept for the border.

```
@interface MyCollectionView ()
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger selectedRow;
@end    

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //update self.selectedRow and either reload entire collection view or just the currently selected and previously selected.
    self.selectedRow = indexPath.row;
    [collectionView reloadData];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *myCell = [collectionView  dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGFloat borderWidth = (indexPath.row == self.selectedRow) ? 3.0 : 0.0;
    [myCell.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:borderWidth];
    return myCell;
}
```

Comment: good, except your equality check is too strong.  indexPath will not be deeply equal to self.borderedCellIndexPath (selectedIndexPath is a better name).  Use [indexPath compare: self.borderedCellIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame instead.

Comment: you could also just reload at the particular index path.  prettier.

Comment: @danh The OP would need to reload the selected index path AND the previously selected index path.

Comment: Oh yeah, good point.  I think that's still better advice to reload those two.

Comment: But what about your logic error?  I would up vote but this solution is only almost right.  It won't work as coded.

Comment: It's worth noting that the scalar representation of the selection limits this to working only for collection views with one section.  A more robust solution would record the indexPath (not just the row) of the selection, then use equivalence (not ==) to configure the cell.